# Going more than 1 level deep in the Laravel message bag

Tags: laravel

I'm taking a JSON response from an API I am consuming and sending it straight through to the error bag so that it appears like this:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to access the `message` that says `Student does not exist` in blade the example above.

Usually I'd use something like `$errors->first("message")` in blade to pull it out but things like `$errors->first->error("message")` and `$errors->first->error['message']` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code:

```
{{ $errors->first('student') }}
```

For ex,

```
<input type="text" name="student">
<div class="error">{{ $errors->first('student') }}</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, because there isn't anything in the error bag called 'student'

Comment: You may print all error like:
`foreach ($messages->all() as $message) {
    echo $message;
}`
for more information refer laravel [Error message](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#working-with-error-messages) document.